# Leaflet Rotate Only Shadow of an Icon

Tags: javascript, leaflet, rotation, marker, leaflet.markercluster

I need a way to **rotate only the shadow of the icon** which is linked to my marker.

I'm using this plugin for rotation : https://github.com/hanying33/Leaflet.RotatedMarkerWithShadow

The example below rotate both shadow and icon :

```
var my_icon = L.icon({
            iconUrl: crisi_icon,                            
            iconSize: [34, 34],                                         
            iconAnchor: [17, 17],                                
            shadowUrl: path_azimuth,
            shadowSize:[34,34],
            shadowAnchor:[17,34],
          });

var my_marker = L.marker([feature.geometry.coordinates[1],feature.geometry.coordinates[0]],{
                icon: my_icon,
                rotationAngle: isNaN(feature.properties.Azimuth) ? 0 : feature.properties.Azimuth,
                rotationOrigin: mon_icon[1],
                rotationShadowOrigin:'center center',
                draggable:false,
            });
```

The result is like this :

[image]

But I need something like this :

[image]

Comment: The library you mentioned actually rotates both the icon and the shadow. It does not provide a function to rotate them separately. But you can actually modify the `leaflet.rotatedMarker.js` to rotate only one of them

Comment: Use two overlapping markers instead.

Comment: @firatozcevahir how can I change this script please ? because I have commented this part of code but markers are not showing correctly                                                   
```/*  if (this._icon)
           this._icon.style[L.DomUtil.TRANSFORM+'Origin'] = this.options.rotationOrigin;*/ ```

Comment: according to this script https://github.com/hanying33/Leaflet.RotatedMarkerWithShadow/blob/master/leaflet.rotatedMarker.js you need to comment these lines only `38-39-44-45`

Comment: @firatozcevahir thank you so much, it works fine,. still finding the best origin orientation of the arrow.

Comment: @yassinemt you can ask another question  about that